# How to be an effective cleric in Aion?

Tags: aion

I just started playing free-to-play Aion through Gameforge on Euro servers and it's pretty fun. I was just wondering if anyone had good builds/strategy to be the most effective cleric in a party.

Comment: potentially off-topic, but are there still 100s of "fkjhsdfjhghjrgthr" named-characters running the auction house/bot-grinding low level zones?  Because I really liked that game but the botting was just too much for me

Comment: no not that I've seen. There are 2 different Aion's..of sorts..from what I can tell. NCSoft Aion is a North American version, but I am playing on the euro one. was that happening on the euro one or the ncsoft version?

Comment: NCSoft Aion - it was also littered with adds for lineage II ...

Comment: LOL how sad! I heard it didn't do well (aion) when it came out with leveling being too hard and too much focus on grinding-only leveling. You should check out the euro one that is free-to-play. It's pretty fun and there are a good number of people on there. I play it through the gameforge client. just downloaded it here and registered: http://www.aionfreetoplay.com/website/ also, they supposedly made leveling less difficult and added a lot more questing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good cleric? (my further way, cleric lvl 23 so far but straight way in plan):

First of all it depends on how YOU play, if you are attentive and be able to organise your mana, if you are good at managing your group and know which member is the most important after you and which you can lose sight off, then you already are a good cleric.

To be an "one of the best" cleric you have to take sight of a few stats: important is the healing boost. My slots are filled with evasion-stones, because my casts will be less interrupted if the enemys not hit. Further i have an eye on PDEF and MP. This is my CLERIC-WAY, hope it helps a little. And as said, i am just 23, but very experienced in MMORPGS and playing healers.